# Regex to extract links breaks at slash

Tags: javascript, regex

Hey guys i have created the following regex function to add links to a string that gets passed, the function looks like so:

```
function addLinks(str) {
        return str.replace( RegExp('https://[^/\s]+' , 'g') , (match , p1) => '<a href="' + match + '">' + match + '</\a>');
    }
```

Now when i pass the above function a sentence like the below:

```
Go through codepens and make experiments folder -- https://codepen.io/pens/
```

I get the following output:

```
<li>Go through codepens and make experiments folder -- <a href="https://codepen.io">https://codepen.io</a>/pens/</li>
```

The last part of the link `/pens/` does't get included in the link, why is this happending , even though i have added `[^/\s]+` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could just try to match until hitting a whitespace character:

```
function addLinks(str) {
    return str.replace( RegExp('https://[^\s]+' , 'g') , (match , p1) => '<a href="' + match + '">' + match + '</\a>');
}
```

This might work since *valid* URLs cannot have whitespace in them.  Of course, this regex would miss the mark on a broken URL.

Comment: +1 but see how in the fiddle here --> https://jsfiddle.net/2ajzrfqb/  , the part after google.com does't get selected. :|